# how to find \n in string in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a json file from which I read an array of objects.

Now I have situation where, if some object contains `\n`, then I have to do some extra operations. To check whether the objects contain `\n`, or not, I do the following...

```
String normalString = 'somethin \n and something';    
String jsonString = jsonFileData['some_field'];    
print(normalString.contains('\n')); //true 
print(jsonString.contains('\n')); // false
```

If I do `string.contains()` with simple string it returns `true`, but if I check check the json file as a string `false` is returned.

Why is this so?

Comment: What does "json file's string" mean exactly? When you print that, does it contain a line break where you expect `\n`?

Comment: yes it does makes line break in app

Comment: What is the content of `jsonString`?

Answer (score 2):

The most probable answer to your question is that `jsonFileData['some_field']` is not a string. As you are putting it in a string, the `toString` method is called on that object and returns something that is not what you intend. Thus, when you search for '\n', it is not found.

Comment: `myData[quize[i]]['question'].toString().contains("\\n")` is the code that i am doing and it is string

Comment: If the code in your previous comment is exactly the one that is not working, your problem comes from the `.contains("\\n")`. It should be `.contains("\n")`

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your json content and the exact code you're using to read the json and test the \n ?

Comment: .contains("\\n") works for me.